# Can't always get Swift UIButton to hide

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

UIButton is programmatically created.
At first, it is shown.
User taps it.
The code programmatically sets its .isHidden to true, but it stays shown.
When set true, next line is print that shows .isHidden is true.  (see OUTPUT below)
But I still see it.

HERE IS CODE....................

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{                                    
    connect_dropbox_UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: tap_button_2nd_x,
                    y: tap_row_y,
                    width: tap_buttom_width,
                    height: tap_height ))
    connect_dropbox_UIButton.setTitle( "DX", for: .normal )
    connect_dropbox_UIButton.addTarget( self, action: #selector( connect_dropbox ), for: .touchUpInside)
    connect_dropbox_UIButton.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB( rgbValue: 0x0080ff )
    connect_dropbox_UIButton.isHidden = is_dropbox_connection( TRUE )
    print("show_DX_tap:     is_dropbox_connection", is_dropbox_connection() ) 
    print("show_DX_tap:     connect_dropbox_UIButton.isHidden", connect_dropbox_UIButton.isHidden )    // shows "true"

    connect_dropbox_UIButton.isEnabled = TRUE

    self.view.addSubview( connect_dropbox_UIButton )
}



func is_dropbox_connection( _ is_dump: Bool = false ) -> Bool
{
    if DBG_UPLOAD || is_dump {
        print("is_DROP_1_authorizedClient_successful", is_DROP_1_authorizedClient_successful ) 
        print("is_DROP_2_authorizeFromControllerV2_successful", is_DROP_2_authorizeFromControllerV2_successful ) 
        print("is_DropboxOAuthCompletion", is_DropboxOAuthCompletion ) 
    }
    // Abort if no dropbox access before session:
    if !is_DROP_1_authorizedClient_successful                       // DX API access is ok
        ||  !is_DROP_2_authorizeFromControllerV2_successful         // always set TRUE
        ||  !is_DropboxOAuthCompletion            // call back sets TRUE or false
    {
        return false
    }
    else 
    {
        return TRUE
    }
}
```

HERE IS OUTPUT.....................

> is_DROP_1_authorizedClient_successful true
> is_DROP_2_authorizeFromControllerV2_successful true
> is_DropboxOAuthCompletion true show_DX_tap:     is_dropbox_connection
> true show_DX_tap:     connect_dropbox_UIButton.isHidden true

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code and changed `TRUE` to `true`, and the button was hidden for me.

However, based on the code snippets you posted, the user would never get the chance to interact with the button because you don't add it as a subview until *after* you already set `.isHidden` to `true`. If you are seeing a button, it is either a different button or you are adding and modifying this one somewhere else. I would double check where in your code that happens - the logic in these two code snippets seems to behave the way you intended it to.